# Soap UI problem with response: getting response; null

Tags: java, soapui, jena

I have java application with web services. I am using Jena TDB and it works fine with soapUi when i have thousand objects. When i add 1 milion objects in jena i have problem to get the response from all objects that are stored in Jena.

> Error getting response; null

I tried to change timeout, max size to 0, dump file, also i changed Socket timeout to 0 but did not help.

So my question is how to get the whole response of 1 million objects in SoapUI.

Comment: sounds like a Q to be directed to SoapUI Support, but you might want to check the raw response so you can maybe see more info about it. also it might be that your client has set a timeout, thus because the response is really big it will timeout and sends you the null RS.

Comment: Yes but SoapUi has support only for SoapUi Pro version and not for open source..

Comment: anyhow, chec k the rest of what i said. maybe thats your problem. if thats so ask your RS provider to up the timetout time. or response line/data limit

Comment: I tried with java code so i have the response but i want to receive the response in soap UI too.

Comment: i was talking about the soapUI....